# Custom URL scheme not opening app on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, url-scheme, kindle-fire

I have an android app that uses a custom URL scheme. Works fine for opening the app on regular android devices, but on Kindle Fire devices nothing happens.

My app is receiving the link, and how I handle it is I have an dummy activity that doesn't display which processes the link and opens the correct activity - or sends a broadcast currently open activities to handle the information. I can see in the logs that Amazon is trying to open that activity, and as a result it doesn't open the app at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get around this?

Here is my dummy activity in my manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".LinkHandlerActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the code in my dummy activity that opens the correct activity

```
private void broadcastLink(Bundle bundle) {


    if (LinkManager.getInstance() == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("info", bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent("deep-link-received");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
        intent.putExtra("info", bundle);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Here is the logs from the device whenever a link is tapped on in the Silk Browser

```
03-09 10:56:47.274 463-765/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {xxxx} from pid 6800
03-09 10:56:47.274 463-765/? W/ActivityManager: Input dispatching paused for current ActivityRecord: ActivityRecord{424a4c48 u0 com.testlink.testlinkapp/.LinkHandlerActivity t14}
03-09 10:56:47.321 8868-8868/? I/Activity: No ActvityExender defined. Proceed with default activity behavior.
03-09 10:56:47.321 463-473/? D/AmazonTransitionManager: openingActivityName = com.testlink.testlinkapp.LinkHandlerActivity, animationType = Activity open/close (tablet:FADE phone:SLIDE)
03-09 10:56:47.329 463-807/? I/ActivityManager: Next activity is on the same task, skipping moveHomeToTop()
```

Thanks